# how to get date from datepick jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I followed the [documentation](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html/#getset) of datepick plugin to get the date on a div(`.button`) click but i couldn't make it.

CODE

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ddd').datepick();

$('.button').click(function(){

var dates = $('#ddd').datepick('getDate');
   var value = ''; 
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) { 
        value += (i == 0 ? '' : ',') + $.datepick.formatDate(dates[i]); 
    } 
alert(value);
alert(dates);
});
```

I tried alerting both values and dates to know whether it is array problem or something but both where not working when i click on the div.

What mistake am i making? How to get the date?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xYJN3/)

Comment: You have to select date first, This might help [set date first](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/xYJN3/1/)

Comment: It seems to be working. Select date first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use **[setDate()](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html#getset)** function so that the `datepicker` know what is the default date after you initialize it:

```
$('#ddd').datepick('setDate',0);
```

`0` here is today's date. You can provide one value, two values (for a range), or mutliple values in an array when setting the dates

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xYJN3/2/)